# Как вручную задать значение поля autoincrement?

Tags: mysql

Допустим есть таблица `table` с полями `id` и `name`. В ней пять записей, `id` у нас `autoincrement`, соответственно значения проставлены с `1` до `5`. Но, допустим ситуацию, когда при добавлении 6й записи в таблицу, `id` нужно установить вручную, например нам нужна следующая строка с `id = 10`. Как быть в такой ситуации? Можно ли так делать? И что будет потом, когда у `id` значение `autoincrement` будет на очереди - `10`?

Как решают такие задачи?

Comment: Если приходят в голову мысли задавать автоинкремент вручную, значит используете его не по назначению.

Comment: @Sergey, такие задачи часто возникают, например, если нужно сливать несколько баз данных в одну. Другое дело, что в коде приложения установкой этого параметра лучше не злоупотреблять. Однако sunu0074 по-моему не сообщает о том, собирается выполнять эту операцию в приложении.

Comment: Если в двух и более базах один и тот же автоинкрементный id назначен разным сущностям, то что же делать? В таком случае неизбежно назначение новых id. Перед тем как или во время слития записи в новую базу, ей назначается другой id путём того же автоинкремента по новой базе, а вовсе не ручная замена, от которой только вред.

Comment: @cheops да, именно из-за этого боюсь что возникнет эта проблема

Comment: @Sergey ну а если у этих id много зависимостей? Тогда как быть?

Comment: Как? Новые ссылки конечно прописывать. Если только не хотите, чтобы они ссылались в новой базе на посторонние записи, которые были в этой базе до слияния. Других вариантов нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы установить значение `AUTO_INCREMENT` можно воспользоваться запросом `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;
```

Следующее значение будет 10, потом значения пойдут дальше 11, 12, 13 и т.д.