# Как добавлять ID записи с определенного числа?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть простая база mysql с новостями.
Есть поле ID с автоматическим добавлением id для новых записей.
Как сделать в phpmyadmin, чтобы новые записи начинались не с 1 id, а с 1000 например и далее шли 1001, 1002 и т.д.?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522988

Comment: @andreymal будет работать до перезапуска сервера

Comment: @AntonShchyrov автоинкремент хранится в базе постоянно, и к InnoDB это тоже относится

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @andreymal Отстал я от жизни. В 8.0 они все поменяли